# What is a compact way to create a multi-dimensional array with default values?

Tags: python

I need to create a 4-D array, each of size 3, where each final element is a default. I thought I was clever with this.

```
>>> arr = '-'
>>> for _ in range(4):
...     arr = [arr] * 3
...
```

It looks like I want the default to look, but more experienced Python devs probably see the problem.

```
>>> arr
[[[['-', '-', '-'], ['-', '-', '-'], ['-', '-', '-']], [['-', '-', '-'], ...
>>> arr[0][0][0][0] = 5
[[[[5, '-', '-'], [5, '-', '-'], [5, '-', '-']], [[5, '-', '-'], ...
```

Is there a good way to do this that doesn't have the various lists pointing to the same sub-list?

Comment: Could we get more of the code? Or a version of what the output is supposed to look like? That specific code shouldn't produce that output.

Comment: That's exactly the code from a Python shell. I think what's happening is that after the innermost array is created, the rest of the arrays above it point to the same original one instead of creating new ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
arr = [[[['-' for x in range(3)] for y in range(3)] for z in range(3)] for w in range(3)]
```

Comment: Thanks, I alomst had it. I was experimenting with comprehensions, but didn't realize I should nest them.

Comment: Better if you use `_` as a name for your ignored variables. like: `[[[['-' for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(3)]`